# How to return Double with map

Tags: scala

I try to making token lexical analyzer
and I want return Double type using map in scala

```
    var m = Map[String,Double]()
    def parseItem(tok: Tokenizer): Double = {
    val startPos = tok.tokenPos
    val t = tok.token
    tok.next()
    //(other codes)
    else if (t.isIdentifier) {
      var t1 = tok.token
      if(t1.text == "=") {
        tok.next()
        var t2 = tok.token
        if(t2.isNumber) {
          m += (t.text -> t2.number)
          println("Idenrifier sorted :" + t.text)
          0
        }else if(t2.isIdentifier && m.get(t2.text) == None){
            println("Error!!! RHS is Wrong identifier!!!")
            throw new SyntaxError(startPos, "expected number, identifier, or '('")
        }else{
          m += (t.text -> m.get(t2.text))
          println("Idenrifier sorted :" + t.text)
          0
        }
      }else{
          m.get(t.text)
      }
```

the error code is :Option[Double]
I think return type is Double But I can't understanding this error

Comment: error located last else

Comment: `m.get(t.text)` returns `Option[Double]`

Comment: You can use apply to get the actual value instead of Optional value: `m.apply(t.text)`, or shorter: `m(t.text)`, but I think it's still safer to use get.

Answer (score 2):

```
  m.get(t.text) is of type Option[Double]
```

You can use the apply method of the Map but keep in mind that the apply method returns the value associated with a given key directly, without wrapping it in an Option. If the key is not defined in the map, an exception is raised.

You can use `m(t.text)` or `m.apply(t.text)`

Or you can use `m getOrElse (t.text, defaultValue)`  ,which returns the value associated with key `t.text` in the `m` map , or the defaultValue  if not found.